# Цепочка вызовов

Tags: c++, рекурсия, методы

Здравствуйте. На данный момент я нахожусь на начальном этапе изучения C++, поэтому хотел бы задать вопрос более опытным.
Я написал простенькую консольную программу и попытался реализовать элементарный диалог с пользователем посредствам создания специального метода в одном из классов :

```
class MyClass {
public :
   void method() { cout << endl << "Method used" << endl; }
   void menu() {
       int* choice = new int;
       cout << "1. Use method;" << endl << "2. Stop;" << endl << "set : ";
       cin >> *choice;
       switch(*choice) {
           case 1 : delete choice; method(); menu(); break;
           case 2 : delete choice; exit(1); break;
       }
   }
};
```

В действительности он немного побольше, но концепция такая же.
Вот собственно хотел спросить по поводу применения данного принципа : нормально так делать? В смысле, меня немного беспокоит что каждый новый вход в метод menu() после ввода "1" будет приостанавливать действующий вызов. Следовательно, если так долго продолжать то получится довольно длинная цепочка приостановленных вызовов.

Или же целесообразней вынести всё это безобразие, к примеру, в main() ? :

```
int main() {

   MyClass* my_obj = new MyClass;
   int* choice = new int;

   while(true) {
       cout << "1. Use method;" << endl << "2. Stop;" << endl << "set : ";
       cin >> *choice;
       switch(*choice) {
           case 1 : my_obj->method(); break;
           case 2 : delete choice; delete my_obj; exit(1); break;
       }
   }
   return 0;
}
```

При использовании метода menu(), равно как и main(), освобождается вся выделенная память. Однако, остается длинный хвост приостановленных вызовов.
Может ли такая цепочка, например, рано или поздно занять много памяти или типа того? В общем, хотелось бы получить аргументированный ответ, спасибо =)

Comment: как бы иронично это не звучало, но такая рекурсия как в первом примере рано или поздно приведет к `StackOverflow`, т.е переполнению стека. Бесконечный цикл это обычный подход в разработке. Например, жизнь любого windows-приложения заключается в цикле обработки оконных сообщений.

Comment: А зачем вы кладёте `choice` в кучу? Почему не просто `int choice` и везде обращаться без `*`?

Comment: Проблема с такой рекурсией в том, что её не получится использовать _везде_, т. к. довольно часто метод должен что-то возвращать. А если у вас он ничего не возвращает и вернуть не может в принципе. Лучше управлять потоком выполнения программы при помощи специально для этого предназначенных управляющих конструкций — `while`/`for`/`if`/...

Comment: Влад, я предупредил что новичок. Я пока плохо различаю помещение данных в стек и в кучу просто потому что еще не касался этой темы.

Comment: Спасибо всем за комменты, получил полезные знания =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, реально вы будете очень долго вызывать `menu()`, пока исчерпается стек, но просто зачем так поступать? можно приобрести плохую привычку :) - тем более, что вы совершенно корректно написали второй пример.

У меня только два замечания:
1. совершенно незачем делать `choice` указателем и выделять для него память. Лучше сделать его простой переменной `int`. Конечно, если это просто для тренировки, то ладно :)
2. `exit(1)` - не лучший способ выхода, тем более что ненулевой код свидетельствует обычно о какой-то ошибке. Просто выходите из `main()` - этого достаточно. И, кстати, `break` после `exit(1)` можно не писать. Надеюсь, понятно, почему? :)

Comment: На отсутствие `break` скорее всего ругается компилятор.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! По поводу указателей / неуказателей, я действительно недавно довольно плотно изучил эту тему и теперь пихаю их везде где могу просто для закрепления пройденного =)
Кстати `break` пишу просто потому что перфекционист внутри требует завершения всех путей ветвления данной инструкцией :D